# A linear operator on a $5$ dimensional complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification, jordan-normal-form

A linear operator $T$ on a complex vector space $V$ has the characteristics polynomial $x^3(x-5)^2$ and the minimal polynomial $x^2(x-5)$ .Choose all correct options.

$(a)$ The Jordan Form of $T$ is uniquely determined by the given information.

$(b)$ There are exactly two Jordan blocks in the Jordan decomposition of $T$.

$(c)$ The operator induced by $T$ on the quotient space $V/Ker(T-5I)$ is nilpotent , where $I$ is the Identity operator.

$(d)$ The operator induced by $T$ on the quotient space $V/Ker(T)$ is a scalar multiple of the Identity operator.

My attempt

$(a)$ This is the uniquely determined Jordan Form.

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&&&\\0&0&&&\\&&0&&\\&&&5&\\&&&&5\end{bmatrix}

$(b)$ There are $4$ Jordan Blocks.

$(c)$ Let
$B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\}$ be the  ordered basis with respect to which the matrix representation of $T$ is the above Jordan Canonical Form . The Vector Space $V$ has the standard inner product.

I know that

"Every subspace of a finite dimensional Inner Product Space has a unique orthogonal complement."

and

"The quotient space corresponding to a subspace $W$ of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ is isomorphic to the complementary subspace of $W$.

i.e $V/W \simeq W'$ where $W\oplus W'=V$

Keeping these theorems in mind,

We have, $T-5I=\begin{bmatrix}-5&1&&&\\0&-5&&&\\&&-5&&\\&&&0&\\&&&&0\end{bmatrix}$

Let $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)^T \in Ker(T-5I)$ .This gives

$-5x_3=0, -5x_2=0, -5x_1+x_2=0$ giving  $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$

Hence $\{Ker(T-5I)\}=
\{(0,0,0,x_4,x_5)^T: x_4,x_5 \in \mathbb{C} \}$

Hence $\{Ker(T-5I)\}^{\perp}=
\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,0,0)^T: x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{C} \}$

So, $T$ operating on $V/Ker(T-5I)$ is same as $T$ operating on $\{Ker(T-5I)\}^{\perp}$

Also , $\{Ker (T-5I)\}^{\perp}=L(\{v_1,v_2,v_3\})$

Hence

$T:V/Ker(T-5I) \to V/Ker(T-5I)$

is given by $Tv_1=0, Tv_2=v_1, Tv_3=0$ as obtained fron the Jordan Canonical Form. Thus the matrix of $T$ relative to the ordered basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} $

which is a nilpotent matrix .

For $(d)$

$Ker(T)=\{(x_1,0,x_3,0,0)^T : x_1,x_3 \in \mathbb{C}\}$

Hence

$\{Ker(T)\}^{\perp}=\{(0,x_2,0,x_4,x_5)^T : x_2,x_4,x_5 \in \mathbb{C}\}$

Hence by the same reason

$T: V/Ker(T) \to L(\{v_1,v_4,v_5\})$ is given by

$Tv_2=v_1,Tv_4=5v_4,Tv_5=5v_5$

Thus the matrix of this induced operator

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&5&0\\0&0&5\end{bmatrix} $

which is not scalar matrix.

Thanks a lot for your patience in seeing my work. Do you see any discrepancy there.?

If you have any other metods, please share. Thanks for your time.

Comment: $T(0,1,0,0,0)^T=(1,0,0,0,0)^T\in\ker T$. So on $V/\ker T$, spanned by your $v_2,v_4,v_5$, we get $Tv_2=0$. The final answer is still the same, but the matrix has a $0$, not a $1$ in the top left entry.

Comment: @Arthur I think you are presuming $V/Ker(T)$ is $T$ invariant subspace which was in the case of part $(c)$. But the range space is $L(\{v_1,v_4,v_5)\}$ as I have shown in my answer . So the matrix is written with respect to the ordered bases $\{v_2,v_4,v_5\}$  and $\{v_1,v_4,v_5\}$ .May be, I am wrong but do you disagree with this ?

Comment: $V/\ker T$ isn't a subspace. It's a quotient space. In $V/\ker T$, $v_1$ is zero. So $Tv_2=0$. But this notation isn't doing you any favours. Let's rewrite to be more correct: In $V/\ker T$, $v_1+\ker T=\ker T$ is the zero element. So $T(v_2+\ker T)=v_1+\ker T$ is the zero element. Thinking about $V/W$ as $W^\perp$ will only get you so far, and is not really something you should do unless you're really confident in the first place.

Comment: Oh! , your coset notation has made everything clear. Just a last question regarding your suggestion of not to think of $V/W$ as $W^{\perp}$ .So in the context of my question, $T$ operating on $V/Ker(T)$ is not same as $T$ operating on $L(\{v_i :i=2,4,5\})$ but rather operating on $L(\{v_i+Ker(T) :i=2,4,5\})$ ?

Comment: Indeed, those two are not the same, and it is the latter you're supposed to use. It is true that there is a very natural bijection between $V/W$ and $W^\perp$ (as long as $^\perp$ is defined), but they do behave differently, in particular when it comes to modifying a linear map $T:V\to V$. It is most natural to consider either a restriction $T|_{W^\perp}:W^\perp\to V$ or a projection $P\circ T:V\to V/W$, and this may be done without any issues every time it seems useful. Making $W^\perp$ the codomain, or making $V/W^\perp$ the domain requires extra checks and restrictions to work.

Comment: No doubts at last. Learnt something important from you . Thanks again!